# Why is Ajax not posting to the server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

Can someone please look at the following and tell me what my server is not getting any calls from my ajax?  the alert pops up but nothing to the server??

JSP CODE:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>This is a project to show how to use RESTful</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/add.js"></script>


<H1>Add Employee</H1>

<p>
<form name="htmlform">
<table border=1>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr></thead>

    <tr>
        <td><input  type="text" name="ID" maxlength="5" size="3"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="Name" maxlength="10" size="10"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="Email" maxlength="10" size="10"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<input type="button" value="Save Employee" onclick="doAjaxPost();" />
<p>
<p>
</form>
[<a href="http://localhost:8080/RESTful/service/employees">List all Employees</a> | <a href="add.jsp">Employee Form Test</a>]


</body>
</html>
```

ADD.JS CODE:

```
function doAjaxPost() {  

    alert("doAjaxPost called");

       $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : 'json',
            type : "PUT",
            url : contexPath + "/service/employee",
            data : $(this).serializeObject(), 

            success : function(data) {
                alert("Thanks for submitting.  \n\n" + response.result);
               // response
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {
                   alert('Error: ' + e); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please have a look at the browser's console to check there is no javascript error and no network error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you mis-spelled `contexPath` in the line (assuming `contextPath` is defined somewhere):

```
url : contexPath + "/service/employee",
```

**EDIT**:
Looking at where you're getting context, this would work:

```
url : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/service/employee",
```

Comment: Downvote patrol, go easy bro. Help me out with some comments here.

Answer (score 2):

```
url : contexPath + "/service/employee",
```

Is there a chance you're not defining `contexPath`?

Comment: ok I could have put that into a comment instead but you could be a bit less aggressive...

Comment: +1, Turns out you were right on target, Geekfish. @dystroy, go easy man.

Answer (score 0):

Both the other answers are valid.
But according to me using scriptlets in the jsp page is a bad thing to do.

Instead of that you can just pass the value **"/service/employee"** as an argument in `url:`. Because if you have proper mapping or urls then it would just append this value to your current url on this page and it will execute it.

I have used this in my application and its working very nicely.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.